# Increasing UWP backgroudtask lifetime

Tags: uwp

I need to create always-running task to check data update on server. In bad case i have to make up to 300 separate http requests to the remote sertver to get data. I'm using web api as-is and i can't reduce request count.

Thus i'm looking for way to extend background task lifetime. Is it possible to use ExtendedExecutionSession in UWP backgroud task?

Comment: Why not to use TimerTask which will repeat in constant intervals?

Comment: TimerTask lifetime is strictly limited by 25sec. I need more execution time then "naked" TimerTask can give.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [extendedBackgroundTaskTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-in-the-background-indefinetly) capability to remove execution time limitations.

> This capability removes execution time limitations and the idle task
>   watchdog. Once a background task has started, whether by a trigger or
>   an app service call, once it takes a deferral on the
>   BackgroundTaskInstance provided by the Run method, it can run
>   indefinitely.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
  xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"
  xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
  xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap">
  ...
  ...
  <Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="extendedBackgroundTaskTime"/>
  </Capabilities>
  ...
  ...
</Package>
```

However, this capability is not supported if you plan to publish the app to the Windows Store.

Comment: It looks exactly like what i need, but i'm confused a bit -- is it possible to use extendedBackgroundTaskTime without [registering company account](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8efde534-f84a-48d7-9dd5-fec5043a894c/uwphow-to-use-a-restricted-capability-?forum=wpdevelop)? My app won't be published at store.

Comment: Could you please post example of Package.appxmanifest with enabled extendedBackgroundTaskTime ?

Comment: @V.March I updated the answer for the sample. As I included in the answer, you can use it as long as you do not need to publish the app to the Store.